# Connect to openshift app via lwip embedded hardware

Tags: openshift, lwip

I have uploaded a simple Rest API application in Openshift (starter program).
I have also an STM32 based hardware running Lwip (TCP/IP) protocol and my goal is to connect it to the above openshift app.
LWIP uses a function (tcp_connect) which uses the external ip of the app.

However I am struggling to understand and find the external IP of the openshift service running in a pod
Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you mentioned Starter, I'm assuming you're referring to OpenShift Online. External IPs are not provided in OpenShift Online (as with most public providers), you will have to rely on a solution that can perform SNI traffic in order to access your route.

Comment: Yes  I am referring to Openshift Starter online and seems you are right.....I am still haven't found a way with all these entities like ''ingress'', ''loadbalancer'', to expose the external IP, maybe only someone with admin privileges could do it...

Comment: In self-hosted OpenShift Container Platform (or the upstream OKD), you would typically use either an `ExternalIP` service or a `LoadBalancer` service. But as mentioned, this is not supported in OpenShift Online.